# Can i use PHPMailer to send from my mail server?

Tags: php, email, smtp, smtpclient

I want to send message from my mail server, for example from. Can i use for that PHP Mailer class? And how STTP server checks the correctness of email? only checks that domain belongs one of his existing domains?

Sorry for bad english ))

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use phpmailer. You need to put in the smtp information provided by your hosting company in order to send the email

Comment: I don't know how "put in the smtp information provided by your hosting company " i write meil server, for example i want send from fooboo@mymail.com

Comment: you need to download phpmailer from github: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer and here is a working example: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md you can only use an email address that you have permissions to otherwise your email will be marked as spam

Comment: In Smtp server checks which domain belongs address, i want to create another domain, for example mymail.com, how can i do that? send from foo@mymail.com to boo@gmail.com, i can't do that only with PHPMailer class, in Smtp checks address.